# How I can create a trigger with a derived attribute?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I have a database of a video store, to ask the question that I have exposed, I thought about updating an age attribute that corresponds to the actors, but this doesn't make sense (as I show below in an example)

```
CREATE TABLE dobs ( dob date, age number(3));
insert into dobs values ((to_date('1999-10-04','yyyy-mm-dd')),NULL);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_age
(
    fnacimiento date
) 
return int 
is edad int;
begin
    select floor(months_between(sysdate,dob)/12) into edad
    from dobs
    where dob=fnacimiento;
    return edad;
end get_age;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER agec before INSERT OR UPDATE ON dobs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.age := get_age(:new.dob);
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a function in order to update that column. Even no need to use a SELECT Statement.  Just rearrange the trigger as :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER agec BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON dobs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.age := floor(months_between(sysdate,:new.dob)/12);
END;
```

Comment: `before` isn't part of the trigger name. It's part of `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` within the trigger declaration.

Comment: of course, thanks @Luke Woodward I missed the part.

Answer (score 0):

`Trigger` will be fired once at time of insert or update of record in the table so you will get the age of actor when insert/update is executed, not as of today.

So better solution is to create a `view` instead of `trigger` as follows:

```
Create or replace view dobs_vw
As
Select t.* floor(months_between(sysdate,t.dob)/12) as age_asof_today
  From your_table t
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that it is the best option but I have to do it with a trigged

Comment: Not possible with trigger.

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment. (Do video stores still exist, in the age of streaming services?  :-)   )  Please be aware that, in spite the assignment requirements, storing 'age' of anything is inherently a bad design that you will want to avoid in 'the real world'. For no other reason than it immediately begins drifting into being incorrect the instance it is stored.  Always best to store 'start date' (day of birth, DOB, for people) and compute 'age' at run-time, as 'sysdate - start_date', When you get out of the c

Comment: It's for a project where I manage the movies and series from a database and it's specified that I have to create a trigger of a derived attribute and the age thing was the only thing I thought

Comment: Obviously a school assignment.  Why don't you discuss it with your instructor.  Explain what you've done and the dead-end it led to, and ask for ideas of data elements that would be better suited.

Comment: "Create a trigger of a derived attribute" instead of deriving column for age how about deriving column for times_rented. The trigger would have to determine if it a rental or return or other activity, might be some difficulty there, but it could actually be a useful derived column.